# how to have multiple user logged on the same machine with diffrent sesions

Tags: multiple-users

Is it possible to have to have let's say two users on the same machine where each one of them has their own monitor and keyboard can they both be logged on the same machine on the same time and work on it so they don't interfere with each other?

Same way as when you have a virtual environment and multiple users had logged on the guest OS over remote desktop.

The one that I want to do it on is a PC with Windows 10 Pro that is already running Hyper-V with an active user on.

Comment: Yes, in theory, but to actively do you you need to describe what OS and other details.

Comment: updatet my question

Comment: Much better, hopefully now we can get some useful answers for you :)

Comment: It's called a multi-user or multiseat system.  PCs aren't really practical for multi-user, since after all they are designed to be *personal* computers, i.e. single user.  But I have seen expansion boards to install in PCs; each board had a video adapter plus keyboard and mouse inputs for an additional user, aka seat.  You need real HW to do this, not just virtual stuff.  Unix is the preferred OS for such multiseat systems

Comment: With a single machine running Windows you won't be able to do it without additional software. In addition you might have to look into licensing issues as normally windows is mean to be used by a single user or you would buy CALs in some form.

Comment: There are methods of allowing multiple users to use remote desktop (RDP) into the same machine simultaneously. Then, instead of adding a graphics card per user, get a Raspberry Pi or equivalent and use it as "terminal" to the main machine.